# Rspec set modal visibility to true in before block

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, capybara

I have two modals that appear in particular instances. I want one test that does the instances, and checks whether modals become visible, and ANOTHER test that presumes modals are visible, and then takes action inside the modals.

Assuming this is possible, on the second test, **how can I set the modal to be visible via a Rspec before block?** I realize that the modal doesn't have to be visible in order for me to work with its component forms, but I want to do this because I'm running an integration test whereby:

1. User sees modal
2. User fills out form in modal
3. If user fills out form incorrectly, modal is STILL VISIBLE (i.e., form is not submitted)
4. If user fills out form correctly, modal BECOMES INVISIBLE (i.e., form submit)

The underlying page URL in both #3/ #4 are the same, which is why modal visibility is the only thing I can think of to test (I will also test for presence of error messages, but in this case, it's happened that I've gotten an error message and the form still submit, so I'm a little paranoid).

Comment: What do your seperate tests look like today?  Writing a before block is a term of abstraction and making your tests DRY.  You don't need to write those until you see duplicate in your code so get your tests working with as much code as you need and then you can refactor.

Comment: i don't have the second set of tests because ... well therein lies this question. the first set is manual because of some facebook integration funny business that i still need to sort out

Answer (score 0):

Say the modal was for a newsletter signup:

```
it 'valid modal entry', js: true do
  prev_count = NewsletterSubscribers.all.count
  visit_page
  click_modal_thing
  fill_in "Email", with: "test@test.com"
  click_button "Submit"

  expect(page).to have_content "Successfully signed up for newsletter"
  expect(NewsletterSubscribers.all.count).to eq prev_count + 1
end

it 'invalid modal entry', js: true do
  prev_count = NewsletterSubscribers.all.count
  visit_page
  click_modal_thing
  click_button "Submit"

  expect(page).to have_content "Email can't be blank"
  expect(NewsletterSubscribers.all.count).to eq prev_count
end
```

So then based on my comment I left you last night, we clearly see some duplication in this code, let's refactor using a before block:

```
before(:each) do
  @prev_count = NewsletterSubscribers.all.count
  visit_page
  click_modal_thing
end

it 'valid modal entry', js: true do

  fill_in "Email", with: "test@test.com"
  click_button "Submit"

  expect(page).to have_content "Successfully signed up for newsletter"
  expect(NewsletterSubscribers.all.count).to eq @prev_count + 1
end

it "invalid modal entry", js: true do
  click_button "Submit"

  expect(page).to have_content "Email can't be blank"
  expect(NewsletterSubscribers.all.count).to eq @prev_count
end
```

Comment: So this looks like it uses other tests to confirm that the modals are working. Normally I'd agree with this approach, but per the question, I'm not sure why in this case, I've noticed instances where all the tests are passing but the modal for whatever reason either doesn't appear or does appear incorrectly, which is why I was hoping to use a `before` block to force a change in visibility, rather than go through the user flow

Comment: feature specs are used to test user behavior with your website.  You seem to want to test whether a view is producing what you expect it to.  If the CSS is really the important part here, you can use `within(:css, 'modal-class')` but normally that would be considered overkill.

Comment: So you're right in that I want to test the view. But even using the `within` statement won't help me necessarily, because I don't know what the bug is/ was but sometimes the visibility just doesn't work, which is why I want to force set it to false to see if it turns itself back on or not, rather than just rely on the outcome. What I'm sensing though, is that there's not a way to do this, in which case I will look for an alternative. Thanks for your help!